# Is there a way to overlay a line plot (with a finer resolution) onto a bar plot (with a lower resolution)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have a dataset of performance scores with an associated difficulty value, and I want to display the average performance score per difficulty value. The difficulty values range from 0 to 10, but have up to 10 decimal points and as a result are hyper specific. To make this more legible, I've been grouping the difficulty scores into bins. I've done this at two different resolutions, bins of width 0.1, and bins of width 1.

What I would *like* to do, is display a line plot (using the finer data points), on top of a bar plot (using the wider resolution), but I want the bar plot to maintain its structure. Right now, when I try to overlay the line plot, the x-axis seems to scale to the line plot, and the bars end up extremely narrow.

Here's the bar plot code:

```
g1.4 = ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = grouped_diff_wide, aes(y=mean_diff_perf, x=gr, fill=subject), stat = "identity" )+
  facet_wrap(~subject)+
  ggtitle("Average Performance By Difficulty")+
  labs(fill = "Subject")+
  ylab("Performance")+
  xlab("Difficulty")+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = diff_breaks_wide, labels = seq(0, 9, 1))
g1.4
```

And the resulting graph:
[just the bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MVY2.png)

Here's the line plot code:

```
g1.5 = ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = grouped_diff_fine, aes(y=mean_diff_perf, x = gr, group = 1))+
  facet_wrap(~subject)+
  ggtitle("Average Performance By Difficulty")+
  labs(fill = "Subject")+
  ylab("Performance")+
  xlab("Difficulty")+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = diff_breaks_fine, labels = seq(0, 9, 1))
g1.5
```

And the resulting graph: [just the line plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxDTE.png)

And here's my attempt to combine them:

```
g1.6 = ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = grouped_diff_wide, aes(y=mean_diff_perf, x=gr, fill=subject), stat = "identity" )+
  geom_line(data = grouped_diff_fine, aes(y=mean_diff_perf, x = gr, group = 1))+
  facet_wrap(~subject)+
  ggtitle("Average Performance By Difficulty")+
  labs(fill = "Subject")+
  ylab("Performance")+
  xlab("Difficulty")+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = diff_breaks_fine, labels = seq(0, 9, 1))
g1.6
```

And how it turns out: [combined plot with skinny bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWftt.png)

Is there a way to maintain the proportions of the stand alone bar plot but with the line plot overlayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `width` parameter of `geom_bar` (reference see [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html)). As a very simple example using the built-in mtcars data:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1.1) + 
  geom_line(colour = "blue", size = 2)
```